# What is the full asymptotic expansion of $\sum\limits_{a = 1}^{p - 1} \lfloor{\frac{N + a}{p}}\rfloor$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: asymptotics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have an answer from dropping the floor function is summing to be $\left({1 - \frac{1}{p}}\right) N + 2 \left({p - 1}\right)$.  Not certain if the order of part should be $\mathcal{O} \left({1}\right)$.  Also $N \ge p$ and $N$ and $p$ are positive integers.

Comment: Since this runs over a (nearly) full set of residues mod $p$, it should be possible to compute this exactly rather than an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: Might help if you write $N=up+v, 0\le v <p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** After the comment by reuns, I added details for the closed-form after the asymptotic bounds. We will first show that
$$ \boxed{\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \left\lfloor \frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor 
= \left(\,1-\frac{1}{p}\,\right)N + O(1)}$$
and then, with the implications of the comment, we will show explicitly that
$$ \boxed{\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \left\lfloor \frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor 
= N - \left\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor}$$

**Original**
There is a slight mistake in your upperbound, but I'll address it. We may obtain bounds:
$$
\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \left(\, \frac{N+a}{p} - 1 \,\right)
\leq
\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left\lfloor\frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor
\leq \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \frac{N+a}{p}
$$
where the left hand side becomes:
$$(p-1)\frac{N}{p} + \frac{\tfrac12 p(p-1)}{p} - (p-1)
= \left(1-\frac1p\right)N - \frac{p-1}{2}
$$
and the right hand side:
$$(p-1)\frac{N}{p} + \frac{\tfrac12 p(p-1)}{p}
= \left(1-\frac1p\right)N + \frac{p-1}{2}
$$

This gives:
$$\left(1-\frac1p\right)N - \frac{p-1}{2}
\leq\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left\lfloor\frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor
\leq \left(1-\frac1p\right)N + \frac{p-1}{2}$$

so this simple approximation gives that
$$\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left\lfloor\frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor \sim \left(1-\frac1p\right)N + O(1)$$
in particular,
$$ \sup_N \left|\, \sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left\lfloor\frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor - \left(1-\frac1p\right)N\,\right| \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$$

**Added**
I haven't seen the result given by reuns in the comment section, so I'll give a quick proof that I came up with, but it was sufficiently obvious that I suspect this is a standard approach. $f(x)= x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a sawtoothed periodic wave, with a Fourier series given by
$$\frac12 -\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin (2n\pi x)$$
which converges to $f$ except at the integers, where $f$ has a jump discontinuity. Fourier series converge to the middle of a jump: there is a jump from $1$ to $0$ at each integer, so the series converges to $\frac12$.

If we let $a$ go over $1,\dotsc, p$ instead, then $\frac{N+a}{p}$ is an integer exactly once, so we may adjust for the $\frac12$ and sum over the Fourier series:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{a=1}^p \left(\,\frac{N+a}{p} - \left\lfloor \frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor\,\right)\\
&= \sum_{a=1}^p\left(\, \frac12 -\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin \left(2n\pi \frac{N+a}{p}\right)\,\right) - \frac12\\
&= \frac{p-1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{a=1}^p \frac{1}{n}\sin \left(\, \frac{2n\pi N}{p} +  \frac{2n\pi a}{p}\,\right)\\
&= \frac{p-1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{a=1}^p \frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{2n\pi N}{p} \cos  \frac{2n\pi a}{p} - \frac{1}{\pi}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{a=1}^p \frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{2n\pi a}{p} \cos  \frac{2n\pi N}{p}\\
&= \frac{p-1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{2n\pi N}{p} \underbrace{\sum_{a=1}^p \cos  \frac{2n\pi a}{p}}_{=\; 0} - \frac{1}{\pi}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cos  \frac{2n\pi N}{p} \underbrace{\sum_{a=1}^p \sin\frac{2n\pi a}{p}}_{=\; 0}
\end{align}
where the latter step may be easily seen by considering the real and imaginary parts of the geometric series expansion of
$$0 = \frac{1 - \left(e^{i\tfrac{2\pi n}{p}}\right)^p}{1-e^{i\tfrac{2\pi n}{p}}}$$

Now, applying this to the original bounds:
\begin{align}
\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \left(\,\frac{N+a}{p} - \left\lfloor \frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor\,\right)
&= \frac{p-1}{2} - \left(\,\frac{N+p}{p} - \left\lfloor \frac{N+p}{p}\right\rfloor \,\right)\\
&= \frac{p-1}{2} - \left(\,\frac{N}{p} - \left\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor \,\right)
\end{align}
Finally allowing us to compute:
\begin{align}
\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \left\lfloor \frac{N+a}{p}\right\rfloor 
&= \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \frac{N+a}{p} - \frac{p-1}{2} + \frac{N}{p} - \left\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor\\
&= \left(\,1-\frac1p\,\right) N + \frac{p-1}{2} - \frac{p-1}{2} + \frac{N}{p} - \left\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor\\
&= N - \left\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor
\end{align}

Comment: Let $s(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor-1/2$. Then $\sum_{a=1}^{p} s(\frac{N+a}{p}) = 0$ and $\sum_{a= 1}^{p-1} \lfloor \frac{N+a}{p} \rfloor =\sum_{a= 1}^{p} \lfloor \frac{N+a}{p} \rfloor -\lfloor\frac{N+p}{p} \rfloor= \sum_{a= 1}^{p} (\frac{N+a}{p}-1/2) - \lfloor \frac{N+p}{p} \rfloor$

Comment: Yes, I should have said $s(0) = 0$ and add one more term $\pm 1/2$

Comment: @reuns Do you have any references for these results in general? I was able to prove it via Fourier series, but I was wondering if this is done in another way.